# Differentiable stacks and morita morphism

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, groupoids, topological-stacks

I heard that if $[X_0/G_0]$ and $[X_1/G_1]$ are differentiable stacks, then any morphism between them is naturally equivalent to

$$(G_0 \rightrightarrows X_0) \xleftarrow{\simeq} (G_2 \rightrightarrows X_2) \xrightarrow{F} (G_1 \rightrightarrows X_1)$$

where the left arrow is morita morphism and the right one is a Lie groupoid morphism.

I can't find a proof of this. Where can I find a detailed proof of this proposition?

Comment: where did you see this? I am also working on stacks/Lie groupoids..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik  http://theory.fi.infn.it/seminara/Geometry_of_Strings_and_Fieds/Focus_Weeks_files/ginot.pdf  Page 11

Comment: Do you know that any morphism $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ is given by a $\mathcal{G}-\mathcal{H}$ bibundle??? Any $\mathcal{G}-\mathcal{H}$ bibundle is given by a map that you have mentioned above... is that ok?

Comment: I don't know that. Please write it as an answer below if you know how to prove the above proposition.

Comment: Did you get to see my answe??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}=(\mathcal{G}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{G}_0)$ we have what is called $B\mathcal{G}$ the stack associated to $\mathcal{G}$ which is collection of principal $\mathcal{G}$ bundles. This in your notation is $[\mathcal{G}_0/\mathcal{G}_1]$.

Let $F:B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ be a morphism of stacks. This stack $B\mathcal{G}$  has a special object $t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$, the target map.

Consider image of $t$ under $F$, you get a principal $\mathcal{H}$ bundle $F(t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0)$ of the form $P\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ (as $F$ is fibre preserving, base manifold of $t$ and that of $F(t)$ has to be same).

As $t:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ has a left action of $\mathcal{G}$ and as $F$ is a functor, $F(t):P\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$  would also have a left action.

This gives a $\mathcal{G}-\mathcal{H}$ bibundle $$(\mathcal{G}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{G}_0)\leftarrow P\rightarrow (\mathcal{H}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{H}_0)$$

This bibundle is also called as generalzied morphism and this comes from 
$$(\mathcal{G}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{G}_0)\leftarrow (P\rightrightarrows M )\rightarrow (\mathcal{H}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{H}_0)$$

You can look at [Orbifolds as Stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4160) by Eugene Lerman. Do not think this notes is about orbifolds. The word orbifold occurs only once in the note and that too in last  but one line of the paper.

Comment: I was reading some notes about the bibundle.  For the relation between HS bibundles and generalised morphisms of Lie groupoids, see the PhD thesis (Theorem 1.73) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04209.pdf

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. I understand that there is a correspondence. Is that your thesis?

Comment: Not my thesis. I add this remark for people who read this post in the future.

Comment: @WWK Oh.. That is nice :) You still work on stacks/Lie groupoids? Are you interested in discussing about these?

Comment: Not working on these now...

Comment: Do you know any recent PhD's who is working on this who might be willing to discuss

Comment: Sorry, I don't know...

Comment: @WWK Never mind :)